# When using react-redux's useSelector, an error occurs when setState is called repeatedly in the lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

When using react-redux's `useSelector`, an error occurs when `setState` is called repeatedly in the lifecycle.

Is this a bug? I want to know the information of people in the same situation.

version: 
react: 16.9.0
redux: 4.0.4
react-redux: 7.1.0

```
const Status = () => {
  const account = useSelector(state => state.account);

  const onClick = (nextLevel: Level) => {
    // cahngeLevel() is fetching,
    // and data is dispatched at the time of resolution.
    changeLevel(nextLevel);
  };

...

}
```

> Invariant Violation: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen
>   when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate
>   or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to
>   prevent infinite loops.

Comment: please show us the code that uses `onClick`. You're likely calling it when you intend to just reference it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
`onClick` is just called with a button.
The fetch event and store update succeed, but an error occurs after resolution.

Below is the code.

`<button onCLick={() => onClick(1)}>level1</button>`

Comment: Could you show us more of the code such as where you have `setState` utilized?